# How to avoid spring data neo4j fetching parent nodes as a members of a child collection in a tree data structure?

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm, nosql

**Data model:**

I have a tree structure stored in neo4j, where nodes of `:Node` type can be parents for nodes of the same type. [image: tree structure]

`:Node` nodes displayed on the right. The root of the tree (displayed in red) shares some attributes with the leafs, so there is an abstract class called `AbstractNode`:

```
public abstract class AbstractNode {
    private Long id;
    @NotEmpty
    private String code;
    @Relationship(type = "SUBTREE_OF", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private Set<Node> children;

    <getters & setters omitted>
}
```

Class for the parent node:

```
public class CodeSet extends AbstractNode {
    @Relationship(type = "SUBTREE_OF", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Application parent;

    <getters and setters omitted>
}
```

Class for the child node:

```
public class Node extends AbstractNode {
    @NotEmpty
    private String description;
    @NotEmpty
    private String type;
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;
    @NotNull
    @Relationship(type = "SUBTREE_OF", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private AbstractNode parent;

    <getters and setters omitted>
}
```

**Service layer:**

This method is used for retrieving node info to the specifies depth:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Node findById(Long id, int depth) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        Node entity = nodeRepository.findOne(id, depth);
        if (entity == null) {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException(String.format("Node %d not found", id));
        } else {
            return entity;
        }
    }
```

**Problem:**
When fetching the `:Node` nodes, the ones that have parents of the same type has these parents at the list of children, what is obviously wrong and causes other problems. See the screenshot of a debugger for the described data set:
[image: debugger screenshot]

How to resolve this?

Comment: What version of SDN and OGM are you using?

Comment: @digx1 `org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:4.1.2.RELEASE` with the corresponding `org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-core:2.0.3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Spring Data Neo4j (SDN) when there is a combination of incoming and outgoing relationships of the same type you need to annotate both field and setter/getter of incoming relationship field, otherwise you will end up with incorrect mapping.

This is said in the [SDN documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#__relationship_connecting_node_entities%22Spring%20Data%20Neo4j%20reference%22):

> The direction attribute on a @Relationship defaults to OUTGOING. Any fields or methods backed by an INCOMING relationship must be explicitly annotated with an INCOMING direction.

There is also an issue/feature request created in [neo4j-ogm](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/56) (mapping library used in spring data neo4j 4+) about this.

Comment: So with the current 3.0RC1 release, it should be sufficient to annotate the field?

Comment: Yes, the `@Relationship` annotation is field only since 3.x